# Set bound on picture sizes in facebook application

Tags: facebook, facebook-php-sdk

I try to visulize some profile pictures, taken with FB API.
The 'picsize' parameter I use is set to 'large'. I know there are also 'normal', 'small' and 'square' as possible values, but neither of them is big enough for my needs.
   `'picsize' => 'large'`.
Though, this large pictures haven't constant sizes, which is sometimes a problem.
I wonder, which is the most easiest way to set an upper bound, for example to the height of these pictures.
If the height of "generated" large pic is more than the bound, I want the both sizes to be decreased proportionally, so the new height is exactly as the bound.
Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Image container:

```
{
 display: table-cell;
 height: 150px;
 text-align: center;
 vertical-align: middle;
 width: 160px;
}
```

Image

```
{
 max-height: 125px;
}
```